# Remove element from array if element.to_sym is blank

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got an API class which makes an order like so:

```
class APIDocument
  ...
  def order
    @order = []
    @document.template.order.split('_').each do |o|
      @order << o unless o.to_sym == ''
    end
    @order
  end
  ...
end
```

`o.to_sym` is equal to `''` in one of the cases, but `o` is still added to the array. Any thoughts why?

```
@document.template.order => 'photo_info_disclaimer'
api = APIDocument.new(@document)
api.photo => ''
api.order => ['photo', 'info', 'disclaimer']
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Could you have written `o.to_sym = ''`, when you meant `==`, then looked at `o_to_sym`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, with thanks to @August this works:

```
def order
  @order = @document.template.order.split('_').delete_if { |o| self.send(o).blank? }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

> `o.to_sym` is equal to `''` in one of the cases

Are you sure? I'm assuming `o` is a `String`, and in that case, `to_sym` will always result in a `Symbol`. This means that `o.to_sym` will never equal an empty `String` (`''`).

Perhaps you are looking for something along these lines:

```
@orders = @document.template.order.split('_').delete_if { |s| s.empty? }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Love your solution, but I still get the `o` returned even if it equals `''`.

Comment: @emm `o.to_sym` will probably never equal `''`. Maybe it will equal `:''` (empty Symbol)?

Comment: So `s.to_sym == :''` still returns the empty string. How can I test for it?

Comment: `s.to_sym == :''` can only return `true` or `false`. August, srike words like "probably", "possibly" and "unlikely" from your vocabulary when speaking of the rules employed by Ruby or any other programming language. Here the word "cannot" works.

Comment: I've answered my own question with a working solution that thanks you, @August.

Answer (score 0):

```
@order << o unless o.to_sym == :'' 
''.class => String
:''.class => Symbol
```

- In ruby String is different to Symbol. String is mutable variable but Symbol is immutable variable. Symbol object is same of all context in code.